# Solve for eigenstates of $\hat{P} \psi(x) = p_0 \psi(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Our professor asked us to solve for the eigenstates of $\psi(x)$  for the equation

$$\hat{P} \psi(x) = p_0 \psi(x) \, .$$

The question seems really simple, especially because it is borderline a definition, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.  $\hat{P}$ is the momentum operator, so am I just supposed to find eigenstates of $\hat{P}$, and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4):

At this level in QM you want to flex your differential equations knowledge. In this case you know that $\hat P=-i\hbar\partial_x$ so you are solving $-i\hbar \psi'(x)=p_0\psi(x)$, solve for $\psi(x)$. You can't normalize these states really, so don't try.